# Python - Partially override method

Tags: python, methods, overriding, partial

Is it possible to partially override a method? What I mean for example I have one method and I want to update it with some modifications, but I don't want to change whole method (I couldn't figure out how to update old method by inheriting it, but not entirely changing it). So is it possible to do something like this:

```
class A(object):
    def test(self, num):
        tmp = 3
        res = tmp + num
        print 
        return res

a = A()
a.test(5)
returns 8

class B(A):
    def test(self, num):
        tmp = 5
        a = super(B, self).test(num)
        return a

b = B()
b.test(5)
returns 10
```

Is there a way to update only `tmp` value, leaving res = tmp + num, so it would use it as it is defined in `A` class. Or if I want to update like this, there is only way to rewrite everything in that method(because using super I only get the final value that method returns)?

As suggested I update question with method I try to only partially update it:

```
def _display_address(self, cr, uid, address, without_company=False, context=None):

        '''
        The purpose of this function is to build and return an address formatted accordingly to the
        standards of the country where it belongs.

        :param address: browse record of the res.partner to format
        :returns: the address formatted in a display that fit its country habits (or the default ones
            if not country is specified)
        :rtype: string
        '''

        # get the information that will be injected into the display format
        # get the address format
        address_format = address.country_id and address.country_id.address_format or \
              "%(street)s\n%(street2)s\n%(city)s %(state_code)s %(zip)s\n%(country_name)s"
        args = {
            'state_code': address.state_id and address.state_id.code or '',
            'state_name': address.state_id and address.state_id.name or '',
            'country_code': address.country_id and address.country_id.code or '',
            'country_name': address.country_id and address.country_id.name or '',
            'company_name': address.parent_id and address.parent_id.name or '',
        }
        for field in self._address_fields(cr, uid, context=context):
            args[field] = getattr(address, field) or ''
        if without_company:
            args['company_name'] = ''
        elif address.parent_id:
            address_format = '%(company_name)s\n' + address_format
        return address_format % args
```

So for this method I only need to update/change `address_format` and `args`, inserting additional values.

Comment: You could make `tmp` a parameter of the original `test` function, I think that would be the simplest way.

Comment: Yeah that would be easy, but the thing is in real code I can't do that as I can't modify old method, I can only update it through inheritance. So I suppose I need to rewrite whole method.

Comment: What is the real method? In some cases you might be able to do this with decorators.

Comment: Why can't you modify the original method?

Comment: @sweeneyrod because it is not mine. I'm creating module that needs method from another module it uses it, so I can only update by safely inheriting, so if someone uses original module it works like it should, and if someone uses my module (on top of old), it will work like I created.

Comment: In that case I think the only thing you can do is rewrite the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `tmp` is a local variable of `A`'s  `test` function, there is no (portable) way to access it. Either make `tmp` another parameter of `test`, and just pass in the appropriate value (possible with a suitable default if none is passed), or make it a field of `A` and override that field's value in `B`.

Edit: Seeing the actual code, and learning that you aren't allowed to change it, makes this a lot more difficult. Basically, you would have to copy-paste the superclass's code and just change the parts necessary. The good solutions all require modifying the superclass's method.